# Python - use "tempfile" module to create temporary files on a remote server using an SSH handle

Tags: python

My objective is to create temporary directory and files on a remote server. My script has logic to SSH to a remote server and the link to that server is stored in a variable, say "handle". Now how do I use tempfile to create a file/directory on the remote server using this handle?

Comment: You can't. The module tempfile isn't that versatile. So you need to mimic the tempfile code by whatever means that magic handle you don't show how you create it offers you.

Comment: Is the remote server also running python?

Comment: @tdelaney, yes python is installed on the remote server. Is your suggestion to have a script on the remote machine and run it using SSH handle?

Comment: Not quite. Write the script locally in a string, run python remotely and write it to python's stdin.

Comment: interesting. I will give it a try. Thanks tdelaney..